# Using Columns Containing non-Identifier Characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

can i write a select statement i n SQL Server like:

select * from emp where Emp Name='joy'
or
select * from emp where EmpId/Sno=7

whether spaces,special charaters like a comma are allowed in that specified select statement when the column name is having them.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Joy: you should select Jeremys answer as the correct answer (it's "more" correct than mine). You should be a pale "Correct answer" button beside each question (looks like a big tick or "correct" mark)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select * from emp where "Emp Name"='joy' or "EmpId/Sno" = 7
```

If column names have "funny" characters put them in double quotes (you can put them in double quotes even if they don't have "funny" characters)

Answer (score 3):

Spaces and other characters are allowed, but you have to delimit the identifier with square brackets or doublequotes:

```
select * from emp where [Emp Name]='joy'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it perfectly matched to my requirement...
actually the column names are dynamically given which may have spaces and some special charaters also.Thanks once again.